# Spring + Hibernate: transaction commits but data is not persisted

Tags: hibernate, spring, persist

I'm using the following service-layer class that implements Hibernate persistence:

```
public class AccountsManagerImpl implements IAccountsManager {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountsManagerImpl.class);

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private AccountDao accountDao;

    public AccountsManagerImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        accountDao = new AccountDao(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void createAccount(final Account account) {
        runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                accountDao.add(account);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void modifyAccount(final Account account) {
        runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                accountDao.update(account);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAccount(final Account account) {
        runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                accountDao.remove(account);
            }
        });
    }

    private void runInTransaction(Runnable runnable) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            runnable.run();
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception during transaction, rolling back", e);
            if(tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
                try {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                catch(Exception e2) {
                    log.error("Failed to rollback transaction", e2);
                }
                throw new IllegalStateException("Transaction failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This class, along with entity classes, is in a separate library (.jar), that is plugged into a webapp. Webapp uses this class with the following Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    ">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:db.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="schemaUpdate" value="true"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.rcslabs.webcall.server.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

        <bean class="com.rcslabs.webcall.server.impl.AccountsManagerImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When the createAccount method is called, transaction is commited, the object gets it's id from the database sequence, but the data **is not persisted** (no INSERT, the table is empty):

```
2011-12-12 14:45:22,932 DEBUG: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - begin
2011-12-12 14:45:22,932 DEBUG: org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
2011-12-12 14:45:22,932 DEBUG: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - current autocommit status: true
2011-12-12 14:45:22,932 DEBUG: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - disabling autocommit
2011-12-12 14:45:22,934 DEBUG: org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2011-12-12 14:45:22,936 DEBUG: org.hibernate.SQL - select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2011-12-12 14:45:22,940 DEBUG: org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator - Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Long[12]]
2011-12-12 14:45:22,940 DEBUG: org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2011-12-12 14:45:22,940 DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - generated identifier: 12, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator
2011-12-12 14:45:22,946 DEBUG: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - commit
2011-12-12 14:45:22,947 DEBUG: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
2011-12-12 14:45:22,947 DEBUG: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
2011-12-12 14:45:22,947 DEBUG: org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
```

What is wrong? How to persist data correctly?

**Edit:**

I wouldn't like to use Spring declarative transactions (@Transactional) in the library and depend on related Spring classes. I just want to pass the right SessionFactory to the Manager and have it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

and

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" 
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

then you can simply use the the `@Transactional` annotation above whatever method you want wrapped in a transaction?

i.e

```
    @Override  
@Transactional
public void createAccount(final Account account) {
     accountDao.add(account); 
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to depend on Spring annotations in the library. That's the point.

Comment: ok but perhaps you should add this point to your question then? Just a suggestion ;-)

Comment: Had to use declarative transactions because of the problems with lazy loading. Wish I had a way to configure Spring-Hibernate somewhere outside the library.

Answer (score 1):

Looked through the code of org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.

Adding session.flush() before tx.commit() solved the problem.

Comment: This still causes problems with lazy loading though. Maybe there is a better solution without binding to Spring?

Answer (score 0):

I dont find the problem in you app, but I can answer the second question: "How to persist data correctly?"

Use [Spring Transaction Template](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#tx-prog-template), instead of some own implementation.

Comment: It binds the library to Spring transaction infrastructure.

Comment: @weekens: yes, it does, The same way like SessionFactory binds you to Hibernate.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's ok for me to bind the library to Hibernate (as well as JPA). But Spring is something I'd like to use only in webapp project. This gives more flexibility.